# Why can't I run class code outside of a method?

Tags: php, function, methods, static

I heard static method are used when object has not been instantiated or when you need to call something within a class.

```
class Show_files{
    static private $person = 1;     
    echo Show_files::$person++;
}
```

I'd like this to show 2, I know it will work if I put it in an instance or in a method, but why's it not working like it is now?

Comment: Because you cannot have arbitrary statements inside a class body.

Comment: it will work.but you should do echo inside a function of class.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam: -1, no it won't. that's illegal syntax. You cannot have expressions in  class attribute definitions.

Comment: wow already -2 for asking a simple question..?

Comment: take the echo out of the class definition

Comment: Because you're ignoring the basics of object oriented programmation.

Comment: @MarcB I did not tell his current code will work.I just said he has to write echo inside a function of class.

Comment: You should have been able to find a simple answer using google: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: @shaif: "should" is not the same as "must". should is optional, implying that this code would work as -is.

Comment: @MarcB I think you did not read my full statement.you just read "it will work". OP did not asked for syntax error. He asked why he cannot static method in class. But the answer is he can.

Comment: @Shaiful, I wonder if the title could do with improving - the code clearly won't work as it is. The user talks about a static method, but that might not be what they actually meant.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this `echo` inside a method. And then call it elsewhere (for exemple, your view). Watch this : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Well, not an exact wording. You can call a class anywhere you have loaded it beforehand, not only in views/controllers/functions/whatever

Comment: "method", you mean. a function inside an object is a method.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute code inside a class, but outside of a method. That is illegal syntax. The only things that can go "outside" of the methods are attribute definitions:

```
class foo {
    static $x = 0; // simple variable creation, fixed values. A-OK
    public $y = 1+1; // illegal - expressions not permitted
    private $z = self::$y++; // double-illegal 
    echo self::$z // illegal - executing code
}
```

The $z definition is illegal on two levels - you cannot create $z by reading from the object while it's still being parsed/defined, and you cannot "execute code" (i.e. an "expression") in an attribute definition.

Answer (score 0):

Becouse it's inconsistent with php syntax - you have to place it inside of a method.
Ex.

```
Show_files{
static private $person = 1;     
public static function show()
 {
   echo self::person++;
 }
}
```

and then Show_files::show()

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
class Show_files{
   static private $person = 1;     

   public static function getPersonCount() {
        self::$person++;
        echo self::$person;
        return;
   }

}
```

and call it

```
  Show_files::getPersonCount();
```